# Discord bot crashing after trying to play link(Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, opus

I am trying to make my bot work, yet again.

This is my play function.

```
function play(connection, message) {
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];
        server.dispatcher = connection.play(
          ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: "audioonly" })
        );
        server.queue.shift();

        server.dispatcher.on("end", function() {
          if (server.queue[0]) {
            play(connection, message);
          } else {
            connection.disconnect();
          }
        });
      }
```

and it does play.

```
if (!message.guild.voiceConnection)
        message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection) {
          message.channel.send("Playing tune now, Enjoy!");
          play(connection, message);
          console.log("Playing tune now!");
        });
```

I get my log that it's playing and after a few seconds or so I get an error message

> TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int
>
> TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int

and something here

> discord-music-bot\node_modules\opusscript\build\opusscript_native_wasm.js:8
> (TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int)

Other scripts that are also mentioned in the discord.js documentation I can't install and I have tried everything I could think of.

Comment: Are you trying to play an Ogg Opus file in Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

As sugessted on this [github thread](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3895) you should try using `@discordjs/opus` or `node-opus` instead of `opusscript`.